# Concatenation of strings array issues in Python: Str(ArrayOfString[1])+" "+Str(ArrayOfString[2]) doesn't seem to work

Tags: string, python-2.7, concatenation, slice, string-length

Hi I have a problem with a python script, I don't manage to do a concatenation of 2 arrays of strings it returns-

> SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Here's my script:

```
import os, sys, MySQLdb
# connecting to a database
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="MyUser", passwd="MyPassword",db="MyDB")

cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM MyTable")

db.commit()

# get the number of rows in the resultset
numrows = int(cursor.rowcount)

# Opening a file to write in it a script
fname = os.path.normpath("C:\Users\Me\Desktop\MyScript.cmd")
f = open(fname, "w")

# get and display one row at a time.
for x in range(0,numrows):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print row[1], "-->", row[2]
```

Here is what I want to do; make row[1] String no longer than 16 char
and if it is, put it in the beginning of row[2] and slice row[1] to 16 char

Here is how I first tried to do -

```
#if len(str(row[1])>=16:
#   str(row[2])=str(row[1])+" "+str(row[2])
#   str(row[1])=str(row[1][0:14])
```

But since it didn't work now I try to do it without testing the string length and directly putting row[1] in row[2] no matter how long row[1] is

```
    str(row[2])=str(row[1])+" "+str(row[2])
    str(row[1])=str(row[1])[:16]
    f.write("vtaddapp /Nom=test/%s /Comm=\"%s\"\n" % (str(row[1]), str(row[2])))
f.close()
```

I'm using python 2.7 and working with Windows OS

Comment: You can't assign to the result of a function (as in `str(row[1]) = ...`). You can simply use `row[1] = row[1][:16]` if you know they're strings already.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I didn't even realize str was being considered as a function. I'm getting a new error now though: ----------------------------------------   File "C:\Users\zachary\Desktop\StackOverFlowTest.py", line 35, in <module>
    row[1] = str(row[1][0:16])
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment -------------------------------------------- I'm going to try to see how to fix this thanks for your help ^^

Comment: Tuples are immutable (you cannot amend their elements). You will need to create a new tuple and assign that: `row = (row[1][:16], row[1][16:] + " " + row[2])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your first attempt to following:

```
if len(str(row[1])) >= 16:
    row[2] = str(row[1])+" "+str(row[2])
    row[1] = str(row[1][0:16])
```

My answer is freely adapted from comment by @phylogenesis.

Update:
The above answer wont work because row is a tuple and hence it is immutable. You will need to assign the values for 1 and 2 to some other variables and use those in further processing.

```
if len(str(row[1])) >= 16:
    temp2 = str(row[1])+" "+str(row[2])
    temp1 = str(row[1][0:16]) 
else:
    temp2 = str(row[2])
    temp1 = str(row[1])
```

A simple way would be:

```
temp2, temp1 = str(row[1])+" "+str(row[2]), str(row[1][0:16]) if len(str(row[1])) >= 16 else str(row[2]), str(row[2])
```

Comment: There was a mismatch in closing parentheses. I update the answer, please try now.

Comment: Yep had noticed and had fixed it, it goes past this now but it still doesn't work, I'm getting this error message : ---------------------------------------------------------------------  File "C:\Users\zachary\Desktop\StackOverFlowTest.py", line 35, in <module>
    row[1] = str(row[1][0:16])
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment -------------------------------------------- I tried to comment the "row[2] = str...." line and to change the line "row[1] = str(row[1][0:16])" to "row[1] = row[1][0:16]" but it doesn't work either way

Comment: Yes that is right as well. The *row* variable returned is a tuple and hence it is immutable.

Comment: It seems to work thank you so much for your help, I'm going out for lunch I didn't have time to examine the results in details but from what I've seen so far it worked thanks a lot !

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped. Enjoy :)